# Consultar número de retornos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação em um banco de dados para checar se existe um determinado valor, o que deveria me retornar 0 ou 1.

Na consulta feita manualmente dentro do `phpMyAdmin` obtenho sucesso com minha query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = 'nome' AND pass = md5('senha') LIMIT 1;
```

Já que não existe um registro com o `name` "nome" e nem com a `pass` "senha.

Porém, ao fazer a verificação no PHP ele sempre me retorna um (mesmo esses dados não existindo no banco de dados).

```
<?php

if( !isset($_POST['login']) ) die('Erro');

require_once('../config.php');


if( !isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password']) ) {
    exit("Erro: Faltam dados no formulário.");
}
else if( empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) ) {
    exit("Erro: O formulário não pode estar vazio.");
}
else {

    $db_data = mysqli_connect(HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $total = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = '$username' AND pass = md5('$password') LIMIT 1;";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_data, $sql);

    if($query) {
        $total = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    }
    else {
        die("Erro ao realizar a consulta.");
    }

    if($total === 1) {

        $sql = "SELECT id, nickname, level, active  FROM users WHERE name = '$username';";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_data, $sql);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($num > 0) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $nickname = $row['nickname'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            $level = $row['level'];
            $active = $row['active'];

            echo "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nickname<br>";
            echo "<strong>ID:</strong> $id<br>";
            echo "<strong>Nível:</strong> $level<br>";
            echo "<strong>Ativo:</strong> $active<br>";
        }

        mysqli_close($db_data);

    }
    else{
        die('erro');
    }
}
```

Sim, é um código para estudos apenas... Estou enviando o formulário com os dados incorretos, ou seja colocando `username` e `pass` com valores inexistentes, porém toda vez que envio o formulário ele me retorna os dados do único usuário registrado que é o "Admin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu resultado e normal.
Para ter o resultado que vc espera, vc deve fazer deste jeito:

```
 $query_select = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM TAB";
```

et depois ler o resultado deste jeito (depois do mysqli_fetch_array)

```
  $numero_de_dados = $row['total'];
```

No caso de seu codigo, o resultado que vc tem não e o resultado do "count" mas o numero de resultado. Então, se vc tem por exemplo 14878 dados na tabela, o query vai retornar UM numero so, com valor de 14878. E o mysqli_num_rows vai retornar 1.